Can't upgrade to 24.04 from 22.04
/var/log/dist-upgrade/main.log shows this huge list of things that have no replacement. How is it possible that python has no replacement?
2024-09-24 21:21:04,668 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for acpi-support
2024-09-24 21:21:04,669 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for amdgpu-core
2024-09-24 21:21:04,669 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for amdgpu-install
2024-09-24 21:21:04,669 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for amdgpu-lib
2024-09-24 21:21:04,669 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for amdgpu-lib32
2024-09-24 21:21:04,677 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for code
2024-09-24 21:21:04,678 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for containerd.io
2024-09-24 21:21:04,682 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for discord
2024-09-24 21:21:04,682 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for docker-buildx-plugin
2024-09-24 21:21:04,682 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for docker-ce
2024-09-24 21:21:04,682 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for docker-ce-cli
2024-09-24 21:21:04,682 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for docker-ce-rootless-extras
2024-09-24 21:21:04,682 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for docker-compose-plugin
2024-09-24 21:21:04,683 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for drovio
2024-09-24 21:21:04,685 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for expressvpn
2024-09-24 21:21:04,760 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for gir1.2-gweather-3.0
2024-09-24 21:21:04,760 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0
2024-09-24 21:21:04,760 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for gir1.2-mutter-10
2024-09-24 21:21:04,760 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for gir1.2-snapd-1
2024-09-24 21:21:04,761 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for gir1.2-webkit2-4.0
2024-09-24 21:21:04,763 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for gnome-todo-common
2024-09-24 21:21:04,773 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for gst-omx-amdgpu
2024-09-24 21:21:04,775 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for heroku
2024-09-24 21:21:04,776 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for idle-python3.10
2024-09-24 21:21:04,776 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for idle-python3.11
2024-09-24 21:21:04,776 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for idle-python3.12
2024-09-24 21:21:04,777 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for idle-python3.9
2024-09-24 21:21:04,784 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libabsl20210324
2024-09-24 21:21:04,785 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libaio1
2024-09-24 21:21:04,786 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libappstream4
2024-09-24 21:21:05,114 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libatk1.0-data
2024-09-24 21:21:05,340 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libavcodec58
2024-09-24 21:21:05,340 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libavdevice58
2024-09-24 21:21:05,340 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libavfilter7
2024-09-24 21:21:05,340 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libavformat58
2024-09-24 21:21:05,341 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libavutil56
2024-09-24 21:21:05,342 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libblockdev-crypto2
2024-09-24 21:21:05,342 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libblockdev-fs2
2024-09-24 21:21:05,342 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libblockdev-loop2
2024-09-24 21:21:05,342 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libblockdev-part-err2
2024-09-24 21:21:05,342 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libblockdev-part2
2024-09-24 21:21:05,342 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libblockdev-swap2
2024-09-24 21:21:05,342 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libblockdev-utils2
2024-09-24 21:21:05,342 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libblockdev2
2024-09-24 21:21:05,343 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libbpf0
2024-09-24 21:21:05,344 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libcamel-1.2-63
2024-09-24 21:21:05,481 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libcbor0.8
2024-09-24 21:21:05,674 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libclamav9
2024-09-24 21:21:05,930 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libcodec2-1.0
2024-09-24 21:21:05,930 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libcolamd2
2024-09-24 21:21:06,096 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libcupsfilters1
2024-09-24 21:21:06,289 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libdav1d5
2024-09-24 21:21:06,390 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libdmapsharing-3.0-2
2024-09-24 21:21:06,390 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libdns-export1110
2024-09-24 21:21:06,391 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libdrm-amdgpu-amdgpu1
2024-09-24 21:21:06,391 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libdrm-amdgpu-amdgpu1:i386
2024-09-24 21:21:06,391 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libdrm-amdgpu-common
2024-09-24 21:21:06,391 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libdrm-amdgpu-radeon1
2024-09-24 21:21:06,391 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libdrm-amdgpu-radeon1:i386
2024-09-24 21:21:06,391 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libdrm2-amdgpu
2024-09-24 21:21:06,391 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libdrm2-amdgpu:i386
2024-09-24 21:21:06,540 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libebackend-1.2-10
2024-09-24 21:21:06,540 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libebook-1.2-20
2024-09-24 21:21:06,540 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libebook-contacts-1.2-3
2024-09-24 21:21:06,540 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libecal-2.0-1
2024-09-24 21:21:06,541 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libedata-book-1.2-26
2024-09-24 21:21:06,541 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libedata-cal-2.0-1
2024-09-24 21:21:06,541 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libedataserver-1.2-26
2024-09-24 21:21:06,541 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libedataserverui-1.2-3
2024-09-24 21:21:06,647 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libegl1-amdgpu-mesa
2024-09-24 21:21:06,647 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libegl1-amdgpu-mesa-drivers
2024-09-24 21:21:06,647 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libegl1-amdgpu-mesa-drivers:i386
2024-09-24 21:21:06,647 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libegl1-amdgpu-mesa:i386
2024-09-24 21:21:06,973 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libffi7
2024-09-24 21:21:06,974 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libflac8
2024-09-24 21:21:06,975 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libfontembed1
2024-09-24 21:21:07,399 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libfwupdplugin5
2024-09-24 21:21:07,487 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libgbm1-amdgpu
2024-09-24 21:21:07,487 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libgbm1-amdgpu:i386
2024-09-24 21:21:07,630 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libgeocode-glib0
2024-09-24 21:21:07,639 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri
2024-09-24 21:21:07,639 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri:i386
2024-09-24 21:21:07,640 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-glx
2024-09-24 21:21:07,640 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-glx:i386
2024-09-24 21:21:07,640 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libglapi-amdgpu-mesa
2024-09-24 21:21:07,640 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libglapi-amdgpu-mesa:i386
2024-09-24 21:21:07,788 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libgnome-bg-4-1
2024-09-24 21:21:07,851 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libgnome-desktop-3-19
2024-09-24 21:21:07,852 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libgnome-desktop-4-1
2024-09-24 21:21:07,852 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libgnome-todo
2024-09-24 21:21:07,914 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libgoa-backend-1.0-1
2024-09-24 21:21:08,278 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libgs9
2024-09-24 21:21:08,278 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libgs9-common
2024-09-24 21:21:08,278 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libgsoap-2.8.117
2024-09-24 21:21:08,348 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libgssdp-1.2-0
2024-09-24 21:21:08,579 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libgupnp-1.2-1
2024-09-24 21:21:08,580 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libgupnp-igd-1.0-4
2024-09-24 21:21:08,580 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libgweather-3-16
2024-09-24 21:21:08,580 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libgweather-common
2024-09-24 21:21:08,770 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libicu70
2024-09-24 21:21:08,770 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libicu70:i386
2024-09-24 21:21:08,916 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libilmbase25
2024-09-24 21:21:08,916 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libisc-export1105
2024-09-24 21:21:08,917 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libiw30
2024-09-24 21:21:08,917 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18
2024-09-24 21:21:08,987 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libldap-2.5-0
2024-09-24 21:21:09,292 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libllvm16.0.50701-amdgpu
2024-09-24 21:21:09,292 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libllvm16.0.50701-amdgpu:i386
2024-09-24 21:21:09,428 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libmagick++-6.q16-8
2024-09-24 21:21:09,428 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libmagickcore-6.q16-6
2024-09-24 21:21:09,428 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libmagickcore-6.q16-6-extra
2024-09-24 21:21:09,428 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libmagickwand-6.q16-6
2024-09-24 21:21:09,491 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libmozjs-91-0
2024-09-24 21:21:09,491 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libmpdec3
2024-09-24 21:21:09,869 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libmutter-10-0
2024-09-24 21:21:09,930 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libnautilus-extension1a
2024-09-24 21:21:09,930 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libncurses5
2024-09-24 21:21:09,930 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libnetplan0
2024-09-24 21:21:10,025 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libnfs13
2024-09-24 21:21:10,274 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libopenexr25
2024-09-24 21:21:10,274 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libopenh264-6
2024-09-24 21:21:10,390 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for liborcus-0.17-0
2024-09-24 21:21:10,390 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for liborcus-parser-0.17-0
2024-09-24 21:21:10,550 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libperl5.34
2024-09-24 21:21:10,711 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libplist3
2024-09-24 21:21:10,886 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libpoppler118
2024-09-24 21:21:10,886 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libpostproc55
2024-09-24 21:21:10,886 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libpq-dev
2024-09-24 21:21:10,886 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libpq5
2024-09-24 21:21:10,887 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libprocps8
2024-09-24 21:21:10,887 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libprotobuf23
2024-09-24 21:21:10,933 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libpulsedsp
2024-09-24 21:21:10,933 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libpython3.10
2024-09-24 21:21:10,933 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libpython3.10-dbg
2024-09-24 21:21:10,933 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libpython3.10-dev
2024-09-24 21:21:10,933 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libpython3.10-minimal
2024-09-24 21:21:10,933 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libpython3.10-stdlib
2024-09-24 21:21:10,934 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libpython3.10-testsuite
2024-09-24 21:21:10,934 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libpython3.11-minimal
2024-09-24 21:21:10,934 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libpython3.11-stdlib
2024-09-24 21:21:10,934 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libpython3.11-testsuite
2024-09-24 21:21:10,988 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libpython3.12-dev
2024-09-24 21:21:10,988 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libpython3.12-minimal
2024-09-24 21:21:10,989 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libpython3.12-stdlib
2024-09-24 21:21:10,989 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libpython3.12-testsuite
2024-09-24 21:21:10,989 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libpython3.9
2024-09-24 21:21:10,989 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libpython3.9-dev
2024-09-24 21:21:10,989 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libpython3.9-minimal
2024-09-24 21:21:10,989 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libpython3.9-stdlib
2024-09-24 21:21:10,989 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libpython3.9-testsuite
2024-09-24 21:21:10,989 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libqpdf28
2024-09-24 21:21:11,614 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libraw20
2024-09-24 21:21:11,803 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libreoffice-pdfimport
2024-09-24 21:21:11,803 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for librest-0.7-0
2024-09-24 21:21:11,871 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libruby3.0
2024-09-24 21:21:11,878 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for librygel-core-2.6-2
2024-09-24 21:21:11,878 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for librygel-db-2.6-2
2024-09-24 21:21:11,878 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for librygel-renderer-2.6-2
2024-09-24 21:21:11,878 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for librygel-server-2.6-2
2024-09-24 21:21:11,880 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libsgutils2-2
2024-09-24 21:21:11,938 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libsnapd-glib1
2024-09-24 21:21:12,235 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libsrt1.4-gnutls
2024-09-24 21:21:12,335 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libsuitesparseconfig5
2024-09-24 21:21:12,335 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libswresample3
2024-09-24 21:21:12,335 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libswscale5
2024-09-24 21:21:12,387 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libtiff5
2024-09-24 21:21:12,387 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libtiffxx5
2024-09-24 21:21:12,387 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libtinfo-dev
2024-09-24 21:21:12,387 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libtinfo5
2024-09-24 21:21:12,534 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libtss2-mu0
2024-09-24 21:21:12,772 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libunistring2
2024-09-24 21:21:12,773 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libunistring2:i386
2024-09-24 21:21:13,197 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libvpx7
2024-09-24 21:21:13,198 DEBUG Failed to find a reppatslacement for libwayland-amdgpu-client0
2024-09-24 21:21:13,198 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libwayland-amdgpu-client0:i386
2024-09-24 21:21:13,198 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libwayland-amdgpu-egl1:i386
2024-09-24 21:21:13,198 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libwayland-amdgpu-server0
2024-09-24 21:21:13,198 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libwayland-amdgpu-server0:i386
2024-09-24 21:21:13,198 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37
2024-09-24 21:21:13,246 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libx264-163
2024-09-24 21:21:13,247 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libxatracker2-amdgpu
2024-09-24 21:21:13,247 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libxatracker2-amdgpu:i386
2024-09-24 21:21:13,488 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for libzxingcore1
2024-09-24 21:21:13,489 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for linux-generic-hwe-22.04
2024-09-24 21:21:13,489 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic
2024-09-24 21:21:13,489 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for linux-headers-6.2.0-39-generic
2024-09-24 21:21:13,489 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for linux-headers-6.5.0-45-generic
2024-09-24 21:21:13,490 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for linux-headers-generic-hwe-22.04
2024-09-24 21:21:13,490 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for linux-hwe-6.2-headers-6.2.0-37
2024-09-24 21:21:13,490 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for linux-hwe-6.2-headers-6.2.0-39
2024-09-24 21:21:13,490 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for linux-hwe-6.5-headers-6.5.0-45
2024-09-24 21:21:13,490 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for linux-hwe-6.8-headers-6.8.0-40
2024-09-24 21:21:13,490 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for linux-hwe-6.8-headers-6.8.0-45
2024-09-24 21:21:13,490 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for linux-hwe-6.8-tools-6.8.0-40
2024-09-24 21:21:13,490 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for linux-hwe-6.8-tools-6.8.0-45
2024-09-24 21:21:13,491 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04
2024-09-24 21:21:13,493 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for linux-modules-nvidia-470-generic-hwe-22.04
2024-09-24 21:21:13,500 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for mesa-amdgpu-omx-drivers
2024-09-24 21:21:13,500 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for mesa-amdgpu-va-drivers
2024-09-24 21:21:13,500 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for mesa-amdgpu-va-drivers:i386
2024-09-24 21:21:13,500 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers
2024-09-24 21:21:13,501 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers:i386
2024-09-24 21:21:13,501 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for mime-support
2024-09-24 21:21:13,501 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for minikube
2024-09-24 21:21:13,512 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for perl-modules-5.34
2024-09-24 21:21:13,514 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for pipewire-media-session
2024-09-24 21:21:13,515 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for postgresql-client
2024-09-24 21:21:13,515 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for postgresql-client-14
2024-09-24 21:21:13,515 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for postgresql-client-16
2024-09-24 21:21:13,516 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for postgresql-client-common
2024-09-24 21:21:13,516 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for postgresql-common
2024-09-24 21:21:13,521 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for python3-distutils
2024-09-24 21:21:13,626 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for python3.10
2024-09-24 21:21:13,626 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for python3.10-dbg
2024-09-24 21:21:13,626 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for python3.10-dev
2024-09-24 21:21:13,626 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for python3.10-doc
2024-09-24 21:21:13,626 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for python3.10-examples
2024-09-24 21:21:13,626 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for python3.10-full
2024-09-24 21:21:13,627 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for python3.10-minimal
2024-09-24 21:21:13,627 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for python3.10-venv
2024-09-24 21:21:13,627 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for python3.11
2024-09-24 21:21:13,627 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for python3.11-examples
2024-09-24 21:21:13,627 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for python3.11-full
2024-09-24 21:21:13,627 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for python3.11-minimal
2024-09-24 21:21:13,627 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for python3.11-venv
2024-09-24 21:21:13,627 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for python3.12
2024-09-24 21:21:13,627 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for python3.12-dev
2024-09-24 21:21:13,627 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for python3.12-examples
2024-09-24 21:21:13,627 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for python3.12-full
2024-09-24 21:21:13,627 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for python3.12-gdbm
2024-09-24 21:21:13,627 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for python3.12-lib2to3
2024-09-24 21:21:13,628 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for python3.12-minimal
2024-09-24 21:21:13,628 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for python3.12-tk
2024-09-24 21:21:13,628 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for python3.12-venv
2024-09-24 21:21:13,628 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for python3.9
2024-09-24 21:21:13,628 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for python3.9-dev
2024-09-24 21:21:13,628 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for python3.9-distutils
2024-09-24 21:21:13,628 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for python3.9-examples
2024-09-24 21:21:13,628 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for python3.9-full
2024-09-24 21:21:13,628 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for python3.9-gdbm
2024-09-24 21:21:13,628 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for python3.9-lib2to3
2024-09-24 21:21:13,628 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for python3.9-minimal
2024-09-24 21:21:13,628 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for python3.9-tk
2024-09-24 21:21:13,628 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for python3.9-venv
2024-09-24 21:21:13,638 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for ruby3.0
2024-09-24 21:21:13,646 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for thunderbird-gnome-support
2024-09-24 21:21:13,649 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for usrmerge
2024-09-24 21:21:13,653 DEBUG Failed to find a replacement for xserver-xorg-amdgpu-video-amdgpu

After accepting the upgrade via the Software Updater I get this error message:
Could not calculate the upgrade 
An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade    
This was likely caused by: Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu   
Please use the tool 'ppa-purge' from the ppa-purge  package to remove software from a    
Launchpad PPA and  try the upgrade again.   
If none of this applies, then please report this bug   
using the command 'ubuntu-bug ubuntu-release-upgrader-core' in a terminal.
If you want to investigate this yourself the log files in '/var/log/dist-upgrade'    
will contain details about the upgrade.   
Specifically, look at 'main.log' and 'apt.log'.  


We'd need to look at the list of what's reported.  Most likely if you're using an external repository that has extra python versions that's the problem.

It's linked as hyperlinked in the first word @ThomasWard
or do you mean the sources.list?

It is always best to do a fresh install, after backing up your data files. If you have /home on a separate partition, just choose manual partitioning, select not to format /home, and install with the same name and password.

I find it a shame that it is so complicate to update Ubuntu! Is it a distribution for non-experts or for nerds?!? A non-expert should never be suggested to "backup and fresh install" nor to wander through .log files only because the error message is cryptic or incomplete.

@AlexPoca I agree, i had the exact same thought. I remember how the Ubuntu foundation got roasted for the same reason 6 years back from Linus and now we are here with version 24.04 having to do a "backup and fresh install".
